# logging.FileHandler in python creates empty files

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

This is my code

```
logger = logging.getLogger("MAIN")
main_handler_logger = logging.FileHandler("./LOGS/MAIN.log", encoding='utf-8')
main_handler_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
main_handler_logger.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(main_handler_logger)
logger.info("Started!")
```

why logging creates an empty .log file?
whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the level on your `FileHandler` - `main_handler_logger`. If you set the level for `logger` it will log to the file.

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("MAIN")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

main_handler_logger = logging.FileHandler("./LOGS/MAIN.log", encoding="utf-8")
main_handler_logger.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s")
)

logger.addHandler(main_handler_logger)
logger.info("Started!")
```

For easier setup with logging, I would use the [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) function.

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
    filename="myapp.log",
    encoding="utf-8",
)
logger = logging.getLogger("MAIN")
logger.info("Started!")
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning: if the `delay` kwarg is set to True on the FileHandler it won't create an empty file on instantiation.